# DigitalOcean Droplet Error : Connection timed out

Tags: apache, digital-ocean, cloudflare

My website has been affected all of a sudden, and it is no longer working at all. I have shut down and restarted Droplet several times, but to no avail, and I don't know why. Even I couldn't access my server at all either. through my digitalocean console gives me this error:

```
  failed to start console session please close this window and try again
```

or via ssh:

```
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 22: Connection timed out
```

or via Ftp:

```
Network error: Connection to "x.x.x.x" timed out.
```

How can I regain access to my files or server?please.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is one of Digital Ocean's cons. Basically they should have an automated email to let you know of this connection time out issue. In fact, your websites could have been down indefinitely and you'd never find out until you try to ssh into your server, or access your website from a browser.

Just login in to DO account, click on your droplet and select "Power" then select "Turn off" after it turns off select "Turn On" you should be able to ssh into your server after doing this.

Make sure you have a snapshot prior to doing this.

Comment: I did this over and over but to no avail. Unfortunately Digital Ocean gave up my support completely and they told me you should hire someone to solve this problem for you. . The only solution I've been able to restore my site is to use a backup I had from two weeks before the problem occurred.

Comment: Well in that case it's not DO's issue. If you can restore your site from 2 weeks ago, you've probably made some modification to the server, or your server crashed from an overload. It depends how you initially built the server what OS you're using and what you're running on it.